# How should password be transfered for logon in Asp.net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, hash, asp.net-identity

We are using Asp.net Identity (currently version 2). For the purpose of local user authentication, the framework expects clear-text passwords. As far as I understand, this is not the safe method to transfer passwords.

A quick answer can be: use ssl to encrypt password transfer, but this is not a viable solution to everyone.

This is what we think:
The logon form is provided with a one-time random token, then it hashes the password, attaches it to the token and hashes it again. The result is sent to the server.
The server has the hash of the password and the random token, concats them together and if their hash equals what the client sent, proceeds with the logon process.

This is not possible with the current api provided by Asp.net identity: It expects raw password.

What should we do? Rely only on ssl? Is there a way to secure password transfer without ssl?

Comment: Why is SSL not a viable solution? Transferring passwords in the clear, or with a shoddy hashing algorithm is even *less viable*.

Comment: SSL/TLS is your best choice. Every other option is time waste and a security hole.

Comment: In description of your implementation I can see at least one security hole: your hash from the client basically becomes the password and you need to protect it yourself. Please don't do cryptography yourself - you won't get it right. Either use SSL or your clients will have to suck it up and transfer passwords over http - if they can't afford hosting with SSL (you can get a cert for free these days)

Comment: @trailmax You're right, without ssl, we're essentially vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attack, the only thing that this hashing prevents is revelation of the original password and using the hash to spoof authentication in a later time (as the hash I described includes a one time token provided by the server) Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The web relies on https for securing sensitive information like passwords. I'd say follow the standard. Your hashing algorithm isn't as tried and true as decades of https development.

Comment: Yes, but consider a website template which is to be used by many people, especially small businesses/individuals, who do not have or care about https. I really like my code to give them some protection, even though it's incomplete without ssl. What about them?

Comment: @Alireza Since you have a login function for your system I'm guessing you also have some personal data or other forms of transactions that might contain sensitive information, none of which will be secured if the implementer chooses to not use https. The trend on the web is to put everything behind https these days, even "simple" text sites.